# How do I force recv() in Socket to NOT convert my hex values into ASCII if it can (python)

Tags: python, sockets, hex, ascii

I am using python 3.4 socket interface of python-can.  I am having a problem, when I receive the data via recv() or recvfrom() it converts some of the hex data in the message to ASCII if it can for example '63' becomes a 'c'.  I do not want this, I want the raw hex data.

Here is a snippet part of the code:

```
def dissect_can_frame(frame):
can_id, can_dlc, data = struct.unpack(can_frame_fmt, frame)
global dataS
dataS = data[:can_dlc]
return (can_id, can_dlc, data[:can_dlc])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_CAN,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.CAN_RAW)
print(s)
s.bind((can_interface,))
#s.bind((sys.argv[1],)) #used for 'can0' as argument at initial execution

print(socket.AF_CAN,",",socket.SOCK_RAW,",",socket.CAN_RAW)

#while True:
cf, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
print(cf,',',addr)
```

I get "b'\x18c\xd8\xd6\x1f\x01 \x18'" as the output section of the data instead of "18 63 D8 D6 1F 01 20 18".  Do not care about the formatting but notice how '63' has become 'c' and '20' has inserted a space.  Can I stop it doing this?

Is it common for socket to convert the data rather than producing the raw data?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: _"it converts some of the hex data in the message..."_ It's actually converting all of it, even the things that look like hex codes. For example, "\x18" is a single ASCII character.

Comment: Can I stop it doing that?  I feel converting it all directly back will not be clean.

Comment: No, there's no "return as a hex-looking string" option for `recv`. Post-processing is the best you can do.

Comment: This conversion (in so far as it is a conversion) is being done by the print function, not recv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how the data looks when it comes out of `recv`. If you want to convert it into a hex-looking string, then you can use `format` on each character:

```
>>> s = b'\x18c\xd8\xd6\x1f\x01 \x18'
>>> " ".join(["{:02X}".format(ord(c)) for c in s])
'18 63 D8 D6 1F 01 20 18'
```

Of course, this is an inconvenient format for actually doing any kind of analysis on the data. But it looks nice for display purposes.

---

Alternatively, there's `hexlify`, but that doesn't space out the values for you:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(s)
'1863d8d61f012018'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response kevin, the data is currently being output as a string so will take a bit of playing around with to see if I can get it in your nice form, I shall play with it and come back here later.  Thank you.

Comment: I could not get the format to work correctly, it was formatting everything.  But the hexlify does work,